# Combinatorics: generating function problem.

Tags: combinatorics

so i'm working through a few problems on combinatorics and i believe I've made a mistake but i'm uncertain when, if possible could someone point out the error? thanks

> Problem 1: let $a_n$ denote the number of 3-sparse subsets (ie subsets where every element (interger) is at least a distance of 3 from any other element) of $[n] := \{1,2,3,...,n\}$. we are given that for any n $\geq$ 3, either $$(a_n = a_{n-1} - a_{n-3}) \text{ or }(a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-3})$$ which? and why?

i came to the conclusion that it's $a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-3}$ by computing $a_5~\&~a_4$ there is a better reason but unless im mistaken with my answer i'm not sure that's important here. which leads us to the big issue at hand.

> Problem 2:
>   find a closed form expression for the generating function A(x) of the sequence $(a_n)_{n \geq 0}$ which is defined as the following
>
> $$a_o = 1,~a_1 = 2,~a_2=3 \\ a_n = a_{n-1}+a_{n-3}~\text{ for }n \geq 3$$

so heres my current solution and working through.

1. we assume $A(x) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 ...$ exists then
   $$A(x) \rightleftarrows a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3....$$

but from the recurrence relation we also know
$$A(x) \rightleftarrows a_0,a_1,a_2,a_2+a_0....$$
equating the two we see that we need to utilise the right shift rule and the addition rule several times.

$$x^3A(x) \rightleftarrows 0,0,0,a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3....$$
$$xA(x) \rightleftarrows 0,a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3....$$

adding the two gives
$$(x^3+x)A(x)\rightleftarrows 0,a_0,a_1,a_2+a_0,a_3+a_1,...$$

which i believe is what we're after from the 4th term onwards
substituting values of $a_o = 1,~a_1 = 2,~a_2=3$ into the above gives

$$(x^3+x)A(x) \rightleftarrows 0,1,2,a_2+a_0,a_3+a_1,...$$
so we are off for the first three terms by a value of 1 in each placement.

> disclosure: i know adding $x \rightleftarrows 0,1,0,0,0,0,0....$ but i'm not 100% certain the next calculation is correct and this may be one of the locations in which i've gone wrong.

in order to attain $1,2,3$ for our first three values i add $1+x+x^2$ to the above giving

$$1+x+x^2+(x^3+x)A(x)\rightleftarrows 1,2,3,a_2+a_0,a_3+a_1,...$$
which is the same as $$A(x) \rightleftarrows a_0,a_1,a_2,a_2+a_0....$$
thus equating the two gives
$$1+x+x^2+(x^3+x)A(x)=A(x)$$ and re-arranging gives
$$A(x) = \cfrac{1+x+x^2}{1-x(x^2+1)}$$
which i believe is irreducible thus i feel i must of made a mistake, since i'm unable to make a closed form.

thank you for taking the time to read this, any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I haven't checked your calculations, but I don't understand your question.  Why do you say that your expression for $A(x)$ is not a closed form?

Comment: in general when ever i look over the lecture notes the closed form of A(x) is used to generate the nth term of the sequence, though i just realized in order to find the nth term i need to now consider the power series representation of $A(x)$. which normally i would do by breaking it into its partial fractions and going from there, because this is irreducible i have no idea how to move forward in terms of it's power series and thus i've assumed i've made a mistake.

Comment: I don't think so.  You've got a third-order linear recurrence, and the roots of the characteristic polynomial are [ugly](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%5E3-x-1%3D0&t=crmtb01) so I wouldn't expect some simple form.

Comment: fair point, i still feel like i should be able to actually calculate $a_1,a_2,...a_n$ though otherwise i don't really see the point of the generating function in this case or why i've been asked to find the closed form expression for A(x) of $(a_n)_{n \geq 0}$. (though admittedly i see it in the case of others). (thanks btw for the help)

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the problem as your question phrases it says to find a closed form for $A(x)$, not $a_n$?

Comment: Working it out without looking at you working I concur that the closed form generating function is
$$\frac{1+x+x^2}{1-x-x^3}$$